# shell sort pseudocode to C++ code

Tags: c++, sorting, pseudocode, shellsort

```
# Sort an array a[0...n-1].
gaps = [701, 301, 132, 57, 23, 10, 4, 1]

foreach (gap in gaps)
    # Do an insertion sort for each gap size.
    for (i = gap; i < n; i += 1)
        temp = a[i]
        for (j = i; j >= gap and a[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap)
            a[j] = a[j - gap]
        a[j] = temp
```

this is the pseudocode in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Pseudocode) page.
I'm not sure about that if my c++ code is correct according to it. Here is my code:

```
void shellSort(int *array, int array_size)
{
  int e, i, j, temp;
  for(e = 0; e < array_size; e++)
  {
      for( i = e; i < array_size; i++)
      {
          temp = array[i];
          for( j = i; j >= e && array[j - e] > temp; j -= e)
          {
             array[j] = array[j-e];
          }
          array[j] = array[temp];
      }

  }
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
int main()
{
    int sizes[9] = {9,3,5,7,1,0,6,2,4};
    int size = 0;
    shellSort(sizes,size);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout << sizes[i] << endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

but it shows nothing on the screen.

Comment: Well, does it work when you run it with some unsorted data?

Comment: Usually in C++ you would just call `std::sort`.

Comment: You don't seem to be using `gaps[]`, you're just use a gap (`e`) which increments from 0..n-1 ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I added my test code but it doesnt show anything.

Comment: Your second `array[j] = array[j – e];` (outside the `for` loop) should be `array[j] = temp;` And Paul R is correct too.

Comment: @Okan Of course your test code shows nothing! You're setting size to 0 not 9.

Comment: I didn't understand @PaulR answer.

Comment: @JackAidley my bad. because of 0 and 9 is next to eachother. It outputs 0 0 0 0 9 9 9 9 9 :/

Comment: You missed the fact that the "gaps" array in the article isn't the array to be sorted - it's the "step sizes" of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's take this from the top

```
void shellSort(int *array, int array_size)
{
```

Your code completely omitted the needed gaps array

```
  const int gaps[] = {701, 301, 132, 57, 23, 10, 4, 1};
  int e, i, j, temp;
```

The outer loop needs to be across gaps rather than 0 to array_size

```
  for(e = 0; e < sizeof(gaps)/sizeof(int); ++e)
  {
      int gap = gaps[e];
```

You need to use the gap from the gaps array in the inner loop

```
      for( i = gap; i < array_size; ++i)
      {
          temp = array[i];
          for( j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap)
          {
             array[j] = array[j-gap];
          }
```

You need to store temp back into the array

```
          array[j] = temp;
      }

  }
}
```

NB: I don't have a compiler to hand right now, so I haven't checked that, but I think it's right.

Also, a few minor points, this:

```
  int e, i, j, temp;
```

is bad practice, instead declare each variable as you use it, i.e. do this instead:

```
      for( int i = gap; i < array_size; ++i)
      {
          int temp = array[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason (no comments were given), my first answer was deleted (typo - you set size to 0, not 9).  The question wondered why "it shows nothing on the screen".  If you set size to 0, what do you expect a for loop to do when it iterates from 0 to < size???

Before looking at the algorithm, your parameters must be correct.  Start there.  If SOMETHING now gets dumped to the screen, NOW you can start debugging the algorithm (if the output was wrong).  If the output is right, then your algorithm is probably okay.

If I am wrong about this, PLEASE POST A COMMENT TO MY ANSWER.  Don't just "delete" it!?!